# Detect the referral/s of Url/s using JavaScript or PHP from inside a Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, bookmarklet, browser-cache

Let's think out of the box!

Without any programming skills, how can you say/detect if you are on a web page that lists products, and not on the page that prints specific details of a product?

The Bookmarklet is inserted using JavaScript in right after the body tag of a website ( eBay, Bloomingdales, Macy's, toys'r'us ... )

Now, my story is: (programming skills needed now)

I have a bookmarklet and my main problem is how to detect if I am on a page that lists products or if i am on the page that prints the product detail.

The best way that I could think, to detect if I am on the detail page of a product is to detect the referral(s) of the current URL. (maybe all the referrals, the entire click history)

Possible problem: a user adds the URL as favorite and does not use my bookmarklet, and closes the browser; then the user uses the browser again, clicks the favorite link and uses my bookmaklet and I think that I can't detect the referral in this case; it's OK, not all the cases are covered or possible;

Can I detect the referral of this link using the cache in this case? (many browsers cache systems involved here, I know)

Comment: Isn't inspecting the _current_ URL enough? If it is bookmarkable, it must be enough to specify the resource displayed and shouldn't be able to rely on previous state.

Comment: I have an entire system, a sistem that tryes to detect the product informations, but fails when the page is a listing product page; The plugin does not know when he is on a detail page and should know it;

Comment: Well, let me ask again, as you're ignoring the question: isn't inspecting the current URL enough to figure out if you're on a product listing or on a product details page?

Comment: i dont understand you; if you have 10.000 websites, each using different types of urls, how can you detect my problem and fix it ?

Comment: I assumed your bookmarklet is intended for a specific site. How do you expect to figure it for thousands of sites just from the "entire click history" either?

Comment: no, for every website; i insert html and js code in other websites :) and collect data

Comment: that's my point, how can you ? thats why i need a out of the box idea :)

Comment: This is likely never going to work reliably. Probably if you provide details about what your in-page HTML and JS do, and what your bookmarklet is supposed to be doing, there might be some way to figure out a solution. Your approach is likely to be infeasible, but you're being deliberately vague with your actual situation, so nobody can suggest an alternative approach. As your question currently stands, it begs a "too localized" close vote, as it is very unlikely to be helpful to future SO visitors.

Comment: You apparently are not talking about bookmarklets at all — those are small(ish) `javascript:...` URLs that you _bookmark_, and when clicked in your bookmark toolbar, they run in the context of the currently loaded page and perform some utility function. They are _not_ javascript code inserted into a page.

Comment: it's a bookmarklet, but it is not the usual small app; it's a huge app,  it's a app that collects product details from all the eShops and creates its own eShop, so that you will know from where to buy what at the lowest price

Comment: Are you trying to build a crowdsourced online shop scraper?

Comment: i am not trying, i did it, i just need this one more module; so that i could give a message to the user like: hei, we think that this page is a list page, not a product page, so the bookmarklet may not work !

Comment: If your bookmarklet does not have undesired side-effects when invoked on a list page (i.e. does not submit incorrect data to your backend), but just fails to do anything (e.g. does not find any data to submit to your backend), you could use this failure to identify target data as an indication that you're on an incorrect type of page.

Comment: the user has to verify the data before submitting; and i always respect the user desire; if on that page someone sells carrots and the user has modified the product name in ... ognions, that is what i will monitor for him; it does not affect others users wishes, even if they are searching for the same product;

Comment: something will be submitted at the end of the process, and i will monitor it; this is not the problem;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can you say/detect if you are on a web page that lists products, and not on the page that prints specific details of a product

I'd setup **[Brain.js](https://github.com/harthur/brain)** (a neural net implemented in javascript) and train it up on a (necessarily broad and varied) sample set of DOMs and then pick a threshold `product:details` ratio to 'detect' (as near as possible) what type of page I'm on.

This will require some trial and error, but is the best approach I can think of (neural nets can get to "good enough" results pretty quickly - try it, you'll be surprised at the results).

Comment: You could also train on URL strings (or snippets).. might be handy if it turns out there are useful signal patterns in detail vs listing urls.

Comment: from the title tag, you can tell where you are, using a neuronal network

Comment: This answer is genius! I am gonna use that brain.js for a game at some point.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't check history with a bookmarklet, or with any normal client side JavaScript. You are correct, the referrer will be empty if loaded from a bookmark.

The bookmarklet can however store the referrer the first time it is used in a cookie or in localStorage and then the next time it is used, if referrer is empty, check the cookie or localStorage.

That said, your entire approach to this problem seems really odd to me, but I don't have enough details to know if it is genius our insanity.

If I was trying to determine if the current page was a list or a details page, I'd either inspect the url for common patterns or inspect the content of the page for common patterns.

Example of common url patterns: Many 'list pages' are search results, so query string will have words like "search=", "q=", "keywords=", etc.

Example of page content patterns: A product page will have only 1 "buy" button or "add to cart", whatever. A list page will have either no such button or have many.

Comment: genius our insanity : i like this; i need a genius approach, or a very insane one :))

Comment: and what if the page is written in islamic languages? :)) there will be no Buy text

Comment: The problem with asking for "outside the box" questions is A.) people don't know enough about the full details of your problem and the real goals. Outside the box usually means getting at the real goal from a new direction, but that requires understanding the real goals, and knowing what directions have been considered, what is feasible, etc. B.) Stack Overflow isn't a website geared towards brainstorming. It is a site geared towards answering very specific programming questions. That is why I answered the specific parts of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't u use the URL? then you can do something like this http://www.le.url.com?pageid=10&type=DS and then the code will be something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'DS'){
    // Do stuff related to Details Show
} else{
    // Show all the products
}
?>
```

And you can make the url something like this with an .htacces file:
http://www.le.url.com/10/DS

Comment: the url may come in many shapes; with SEO, without seo; what if you have 1000 websites, each using different type of links ? will you write 10.000 ifs and elses ?

Comment: Why would you use  different type of URL's? and how would these type's of urls look like?

Comment: thats the thing, its a bookmarklet, it interacts with all the websites, you dont know the website url scheme; you might be using the bookmarlet on ebay, and the ebay guys can change dayly the url;

Comment: So how do you get the stuff then? are you using iframe's to insert the stuff off ebay into your site?

Comment: alright then... Isn't there an div or span or something else, with an specific ID so you can search for that id and then get to know wich page you are?

Comment: you dont know what you will encounter on the websites; you can see in real life, and you realize that you are on a list page or product detail page; but you have to detect it, using software; how do you do that ? and the best way to do it, atleast for now, is to find the refferal/s of the url/s

Comment: What are the URl's of the list page, and the url of the product detail page then?

Comment: you never know; think out of the box, like you have no knowledge of programming languages; how do you realize that you are on the product detail page and not on a listing page ? on a product detail page, the product is there, somewhere, and it has a big space reserved just for him; you know the landing page, wich is a list page; but some websites have secondary lists, third lists and on the 4 level, there it is, the product detail page; how do i know when i am on the right page ?

Comment: can you send me the URl's of an list page and an details page?

Comment: list page : http://www.emag.ro/ ; detail page: http://www.emag.ro/hdd-western-digital-black-2tb-7200rpm-64mb-sata3-wd2002faex/pd/ECGP7BBBM/?ref=hp_rec_1

Comment: yeah, and what about the other eShops that are out there ? this only works for emag

Comment: i need a automatic solution, not a admin action by hand

Comment: well, i don't think that that will work.. BUt what are you going to do when you know when the user is on an details page?

Comment: it ok when i will know that; the bookmarklet does its job perfect; i have to make sure that the user is on the product detail page, and not on website X that has a product inserted using a API, or on a list that changes daily, ordered by the new product on top; my link has to stay the same, thats why i need the detail product page

Comment: i am also out of ideas ... but once i have a history of the urls of that website, i could manage to do this issue; but its hard to do it from the first visit

Comment: i will put a bounty of 400 on this one

Answer (score 2):

I would say your goal should first be for it to work for some websites. Then many websites and then eventually all websites.

A) Try hand coding the main sites like Amazon, eBay etc... Have a target in mind.

B) Something more creative might be to keep a list of all currency symbols then detect if a page has maybe 10 scattered around. For instance the $ symbol is found all over amazon. But only when there is say 20 per page can you really say that it is a product listing (this is a bad example, amazon's pages are fairly crazy). Perhaps the currency symbols won't work; however, I think you can you can generalize something similar. Perhaps tons of currency symbols plus detection of a "grid" type system with things lined up in a row. You'll get lots of garbage so you'll need good filtering. Data analysis is needed after you have something working algorithmically like this.

C) I think after B) you'll realize that your system might be better with parts of A). In other words you are going to want to customize the hell out of certain popular websites (or more niche ones for that matter). This should help fill the gap for sites that don't follow any known models.

Now as far as tracking where the user came from why not use a tracking cookie type concept. You could of course use indexedDB or localstorage or whatever. In other words always keep a reference to the last page by saving it on the current page. You could also do things like have a stack and push urls onto it on every page. If you want to save it for some reason just send that data back to your server.

Detecting favorite clicks could involve detecting all AJAX traffic and analyzing it (although this might be hard...). You should first do a survey to see what those calls typically look like. I'd imaging something like amazon.com/favorite/product_id would be fairly common. Also... you could try to detect the selector for the "favorite" button on the page then add an onclick handler to detect when it is clicked.

I tried to solve each problem you mentioned. I don't think I understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: 10x for the ideas, and yes, i know about the $ or euro ... signs, and i cant say that if i have 10 or 1000 of them on a page, the page is a list or detail page :(

Comment: I think you should just start and do it manually. Find a few sites to use as a baseline. Everytime I've tried to do something like this I haven't been sure where to start. You end up brute forcing it, then notice a pattern, and finally exploit it.

Comment: i cant do it manually; there is a book/plan, and i have to follow that